# Redirect to custom error page after user fails to log in

Tags: login, redirects

When a user tries to log in and fails because the username or password is incorrect, he is redirected to the ugly EE error page saying "The existing username and/or password you submitted are not valid". How can I redirect to a custom page (basically the same log in page with a little red error message added to it) instead? The EE user guide doesn't seem to say anything.

Comment: Have you simply looked into updated the User Message templates?

Comment: Or you could look at Custom System Messages (http://boldminded.com/add-ons/csm) It also supports ajax so you don't need to reload the page at all

Comment: I had never noticed the User Message templates (this is my first EE site), thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Madc

Is this within an EE template? Or are you talking about logging into the control panel?

If you're talking templates, you may want to use ObjectiveHTML's add-on [Authenticate](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/authenticate).  Works like a charm and returns errors inline (if that's what you're looking for instead of EE's default page).

Comment: Well that's a cool add-on. I was going to use the Custom System Message (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) add-on but this is definitely cooler (ok, mostly because it's free), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FreeMember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember), which lets you display inline error messages for your login/registration templates, as well as update the user's profile details etc.